# How do I display function application with square brackets in traditional form?

Tags: output-formatting, formatting, attributes, traditional-form

If I type

```
C[x, y] // TraditionalForm
```

I get something that looks like

```
C[x, y]
```

But if I type

```
f[x, y] // TraditionalForm
```

I get something that looks like

```
f(x, y)
```

What do I do to designate that a particular symbol, say, `f`, should have function application rendered in traditional form with square brackets rather than parentheses (i.e., `ToString[f[x], TraditionalForm]` should give `"f[x]"`, not `"f(x)"`)?

**Update:** Using [kguler's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/77830/12258), I managed the following:

```
Format[f[x__], TraditionalForm] :=
  Block[{f},
    RawBoxes[ToBoxes[TraditionalForm[f[x]]] //.
    RowBox[{"f", "(", else___, ")"}] :> RowBox[{"f", "[", else, "]"}]]];
```

But this does not work in all cases, in particular, when wrapped in a `Defer` block:

```
{g[g[h[x]]], g[f[h[x]]]} // TraditionalForm
{g[g[x] | y],  f[g[x] | y]} // TraditionalForm
{g[x, y | z, y], f[x, y | z, y]} // TraditionalForm
{Defer[g[D[k, x]]], Defer[f[D[k, x]]]} // TraditionalForm
{g[Defer[D[k, x]]], f[Defer[D[k, x]]]} // TraditionalForm
```

gives

$\{g (g (h(x))),g(f[h(x)])\}$

$\{g (g(x)\,|\,y),f[g(x)\,|\,y]\}$

$\{g(x,y\,|\,z,y),f[x,y\,|\,z,y]\}$

$\left\{g\left(\frac{\partial k}{\partial x}\right),f[0]\right\}$

$\left\{g\left(\frac{\partial k}{\partial x}\right),f\left[\frac{\partial k}{\partial x}\right]\right\}$

The second-to-last line is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write a function that processes the boxforms produced by `TraditionalForm` to replace the parentheses by square brackets:

```
tF=RawBoxes[ToBoxes[TraditionalForm[#]]/.{"("->"[",")"->"]"}]&;

TraditionalForm/@{C[x,y], Sin[x], f[x,y], H[x], h[x,y,z], H[x,y], h[{x,y}]}
(* {C[x,y], sin(x), f(x,y), H(x), h(x,y,z), H(x,y), h({x,y})} *)

tF/@{C[x,y], Sin[x], f[x,y], H[x], h[x,y,z], H[x,y], h[{x,y}]}
(* {C[x,y], sin[x], f[x,y], H[x], h[x,y,z], H[x,y], h[{x,y}]} *)
```

**Update:**

```
ClearAll[tF2]
tF2 = Module[{f = ToString@#2}, RawBoxes[MakeBoxes[TraditionalForm[#]] //. 
      RowBox[{f, "(", else___, ")"}] :> RowBox[{"f", "[", else, "]"}]]] &;

tF2[#, f] & /@ {h[f[g[x]]], h[f[g[x, f[z, w]]]]}
{h (f[g (x)]), h (f[g (x, f[z, w])])}
```

**Update 2:** You can also define the traditional form formatting of `f` using `TagSetDelayed`:

```
ClearAll[makeBracketsF, f]
makeBracketsF[ f_] := (f /: MakeBoxes[f[a___], TraditionalForm] := 
   RowBox[{ToString@f, "[", MakeBoxes[Row[{a}, ","], TraditionalForm], "]"}])

makeBracketsF[f]    

{g[x, y | z, y], f[x, y | z, y]} // TraditionalForm 
{Defer[g[D[k, x]]], Defer[g@f[D[k, x], u, f[r, s], t]]} // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Comment: I want to tag a particular function symbol to give me square brackets in TraditionalForm, not to have all functions give me square brackets in TraditionalForm.  i.e., if I run `MakeBrackets[f]` and then `h[f[g[x]]]//TraditionalForm`, I want to see `h(f[g(x)])`.

Comment: @JasonGross,  please see the update.

Comment: That is much better.  I tried using `Format[f[x__], TraditionalForm] := ...` with that, but it does not work inside a `Defer` block.  Can you make the examples I updated the question with work?

Comment: @JasonGross, try `MakeBoxes` in place of `ToBoxes`. [MakeBoxes >> Properties and Relations](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MakeBoxes.html): _`MakeBoxes[expr]` does not evaluate expr, while `ToBoxes[expr]` does._

Answer (score 2):

I would do this by defining a [`MakeBoxes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MakeBoxes) rule for `f` as kglr does in his answer, but I would use the following version instead:

```
MakeBoxes[f[x__], fmt:TraditionalForm] ^:= RowBox[{
    "f", "[", RowBox[Riffle[BoxForm`ListMakeBoxes[{x}, fmt], ","]], "]"
}]
```

The difference between his [`MakeBoxes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MakeBoxes) definition and the above is that the above version produces the correct output when copy/pasted. For example, when `g` uses his [`MakeBoxes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MakeBoxes) rule, copying the output of `g[x, y]` produces:

```
g[Row[{x, y}, ","]]
```

instead of:

```
g[x, y]
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is because some upper-case letters are interpreted as functions

K[x,y] //TraditionalForm

(*
$K[x,y]$
*)

Note that `K` is a system name

```
?? K
```

(*
$K$ is a default generic name for a summation index in a symbolic sum.
*)

However, letters that are not functions are not:

```
B[x,y] //TraditionalForm
```

(*
$B(x,y)$
*)

All lower-case functions are interpreted as arrays or matrics:

```
c[x, y] // TraditionalForm
```

(*
$c(x,y)$
*)

If you want to keep the brackets:

```
c[x, y] // HoldForm
```

(*
c[x,y]
*)

Comment: I want the arguments to the function, and the function symbol itself, redered in `TraditionalForm`; `HoldForm` does not do this.